# for loop in for loop sumation is overwriting data values python

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, overwrite

I have a question concering my code for a data evaluation of an experiment: 
in a first for loop I am opening file after file which I want to analyze. inside this for loop, so inside one file, I want to create a second for loop to evaluate the some specific paramters for evaluation. when I do it just for one file, the parameters are correct, but when I loop over all files, it looks like in the second for loop these paramteres are summed up. so the normal value should be in the range of ar= 0.0001, for one file perfectly working. when I loop over the files I then get 0.0001 for the first one, 0.0002 for the second, 0.0003 for the thrid, etc.

**update:**
ok so here is the whole part of the code. for each file I want after fitting the data to get the sum over the difference between two datapoints in the first column (x[j]) inside the file multiplicated by the coressponding value in the second columnn (y[j]) (each file has two columns with a length of 720 datapoints) and the result of this should then be stored in AR for each file.

```
def sum_list(l):
  sum = 0
  for k in l:
     sum += k
  return sum

INV= []
DIFFS= []
AR= []

for i in range(0,len(fnames)):

data= np.loadtxt(fnames[i])
x= data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]




gmod=lm.Model(linmod)
result= gmod.fit(y, x=x, p=0.003, bg=0.001)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()             

print result.best_values['bg']

print result.best_values['p']
p= result.best_values['p']
bg1= result.best_values['bg']                    


for j in range(0, 719):
    diffs = ((x[j+1]- x[j])*y[j])
    DIFFS.append(diffs)

ar= sum_list(DIFFS)
AR.append(ar)


inr= (x[0]-bg1)*(y[0]**3)/3 + ar
INV[i]= inr
```

Comment: What is `DIFFS1`? what is `x`? what is `y`? what is `diffs`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The relevant part of the code is still not provided here. If the issue is with the result of summation on `diffs` , we need to see all code that is related to `diffs`.

Comment: I have provided it now in a new comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with files (e.g opening them), I suggest to use os module, maybe a construct like this will help you to avoid the nested for loop:

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for i in files:
      with open(os.path.join(root,i)) as f:
              #do your summation
```